# Custom headers with $.ajax type jsnop or json

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I have a problem with sending some custom headers to with a jQuery ajax JSON (or JSONP) request.

Code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-VER",       VER);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-TIMESTAMP", now);
     },
     type: 'GET',
     data: null,
     url: site_uri,
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function(msg){$(selector).html(msg);}
});
```

Firebug shows no custom headers. In addition the url changes with jsonp (can I change this?)

**Edit:**

I found that it probably violates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy but have no idea how to get it fixed (the script can't be on the same domain).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have server access, a solution would be [HTTP access control modification](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control). Otherwise, probably the best idea is some kind of reverse proxy solution, I have no idea how good of support access control has outside of Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, it will be a temporary solution but for the production server I must find another one.

Comment: @veritas, Temporary working solution has a tendency to become permanent :)

Answer (score 0):

**jsonp** isn't XHR (you are simply adding script elements to the head), emulating XHR. Hence, you can't set custom headers.