# How to control the header attributes in a Javascript POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, http-headers

Is there a way to post data with javascript, but set the attributes such as content type, referrer, user agent, etc.
From what I can tell, the only data I can post is plain variables instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded data.

Comment: There are similar questions on SO (duplicates):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759575/custom-headers-with-ajax-type-jsnop-or-json <br />
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073287/set-headers-with-jquery-ajax-and-jsonp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.setRequestHeader( 'referer', 'foo' )` or [jQuery.Ajax();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: You cannot use `jQuery.post()` to control headers. You can use Ajax to set the headers. Half right